# Deploying a Website project with TeamCity

Tags: c#, msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a solution that contains a bunch of class library projects and an IIS website. I am trying to configure teamcity to compile and deploy the website project via MSBuild/web deploy.

The projects all build fine but it seems that it is ignoring the command line parameters to push the site to the specified server

my question is, is it possible to achieve what I am looking to do? or can this only be done with a web application project?

```
/P:Configuration=Release
/P:DeployOnBuild=True
/P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
/P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://localhost:8172/msdeploy.axd
/P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
/P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
/P:UserName=SNIPPED
/P:Password=SNIPPED
```

I've tried both MSBUILD and Visual Studio runners with the above parameters

Comment: Of course it is possible. But, it is unclear from your question where you are getting stuck. What do you mean by "ignoring command line parameters"? And what type of script are you using (pure MSBuild file, .bat file, Powershell, Gulp, Grunt, etc.)

Comment: I haven't done with a website before .. but web applications are very easy to package as a web deploy (msdeploy) package via specific MSBuild parameters.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I am using msbuild. what I mean is it builds the application, it just skips over the part where it is supposed to deploy. I have added the command line arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those MSBuild arguments won't work for a website only web applications.  You can still use MSDeploy to package the website and deploy it but you have to it manually.

Here is a blog post that explains it further.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/23/deploy-an-asp-net-website-not-web-application-with-msdeploy/

Comment: thanks man! Is there a way I can just build all of this into the commands themselves? It's going to be a little tricky passing variables into the manifest files. I was thinking of maybe using powershell to find and alter the text inside them but I think I would prefer to use the command line explicitly

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would be the next question. You could use WebDeploy Parameterization to declare/set parameters using the ProviderPath kind from the MSDeploy commandline.  http://forums.iis.net/t/1179672.aspx