# TeamCity -> Runner Type for ASP .NET Web Forms Site

Tags: webforms, teamcity, vs-web-site-project

We are working on a legacy WebSite which is designed in ASP.NET Web Forms Site.  This project don't have any .csproj file.

[image]

We want to use TeamCity to automate the build.

I am not sure which **Runner Type** we should use in this case.

I tried to create a publish profile and use MSBuild to publish it

[image]

but I am getting below error.

```
[Step 5/5] Process exited with code 1 (Step: Publish (Command Line))
[05:29:12]

[Step 5/5] Step Publish (Command Line) failed
```

Any idea, what **Runner Type** we can use for such legacy projects?

Comment: You can convert it to Web Application Project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb907624(v=vs.100) or just use msbuild with contentPath in those answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14956108/7225096 https://stackoverflow.com/q/37888735/7225096

Answer (score 1):

I managed to build (and deploy) a legacy website using **Visual studio (sln) build step** (target rebuild, configuration Release).
You will find the deployable package in a subdirectory of "PrecompiledWeb"